# Kendo UI grid pagination issue

Tags: kendo-ui-grid

I have two buttons(Apply, Submit) on my website. I select a row(Page 1) and navigate to another page(Page 2) via grid pagination then select another row. I make few changes on the row and click 'Apply'. Changes get applied on the current page(page 2) but when I navigate to page 1 changes does not reflect. When I submit it sends both the affected row with changed values. Which means it changes the values on both rows but not reflecting it on UI. Is this the problem with cache or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe for complete event and refresh your datasource. I think it will work for you. Example :

```
create: {
    url: "http://mycreate.json",
    type: "POST",
    complete: function(e) {
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); 
    }
},
```